# OAuth2 one-time grant for signup and lost password

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, passwords

We're in the process of building a REST service that primarily is consumed by a JS frontend. The primary means for authentication is OAuth2.

We use the `password` grant type for logins, but one thing we're running into is: how do we design the "lost password" feature. Typically this is done by allowing a user to enter their email address and then sending them a one-time token.

This requires the following:

1. An endpoint that is not authenticated. Something like `POST /lost-password` and accepts the email address. I realize this is not restful, but I can live with that. This endpoint then sends an email to the user with the one-time token.
2. After the user uses the token to get back to the frontend, I basically want to allow the client to exchange that token for an OAuth2 bearer token.

So I didn't really see a `grant_type` in the spec that really does this. My question is:

Is this a situation where I should extend OAuth2 and create a new `grant_type` (extension is supported by OAuth2) that is specific for exchanging 1-time authentication tokens with an OAUth2 access token?

Answer (score 2):

> **TL;DR** I would think twice on going with the creation of a new `grant_type` extension and instead would consider the use of existing flows and OpenID Connect in order to replace the usage of ROPC with the implicit grant flow which would allow you to get access tokens based on an already existing authentication session and in this way saving the user to re-enter their credentials.

### Boring theory

That's a situation that falls outside the scope of OAuth 2.0; the whole subject of user authentication could have been considered out of scope if it was not for the inclusion of the resource owner password credentials grant (ROPC) which does seem to muddy the waters in terms of what's in and out of the specification.

However, you should consider that ROPC was introduced as a quick migration path for applications that were storing users passwords in order to function while the user was *offline* and not as a way to address the subject of user authentication.

Not even OpenID Connect which clearly focus on user authentication goes on to specify reset password mechanics as this is specific to one type of user credentials. This is generally left as an implementation detail for the identity provider.

### A look at alternatives

#### Option A <sub>simple to implement</sub>

I'm assuming that you considered, but want to avoid the following option (**A**) which would not require any exchange of tokens and/or custom grant types:

1. User requests password reset;
2. Identity provider sends a password reset code URL through email;
3. User accesses URL and changes password;
4. User logins into the application (ROPC) using new password and obtains an access token;

This would work with your current approach without having to extend or touch anything related to OAuth2; however it would imply the user would have to reenter their credentials after actually completing the reset procedure password.

#### Option B <sub>it may be more elegant</sub>

Another option (**B**) more complex, but still without having to extend the protocols and also reinforcing what you mentioned about the `/lost-password` not being very REST'y. You can think of the endpoint to request and then actually process the password reset mechanism as being part of your identity provider and not your resource server (REST API).

You could then leverage this identity provider session in every OAuth2 flow that requires user authentication.

#### Option B.1

When user access your application you perform an implicit grant authentication request (according to OpenID Connect rules) using `prompt=none`.

If this succeeds, the user already had a session on the identity provider and you get a token. This session would be created when the user changes their password.

If this fails, you show the user your current login interface and use ROPC to get the token.

#### Option B.2

You dump ROPC and start using implicit grant for everything. This requires that you move the authentication user interface out of your client application and into your *identity provider* and then need to handle the specifics of a redirect-based flow instead of the more direct request/response nature of ROPC.

With this setup, both login and password reset operations would create the notion of an authentication session that could then be leveraged by your client application as a way to get tokens without bothering the user - through the implicit grant.

### Final notes

Personally I think there are some advantages on having a more full-fledged identity provider; additionally, the implicit grant with `prompt=none` support also seems a very nice solution for the problem of how to refresh tokens in SPAs.

> While SPAs cannot use refresh tokens, they can take advantage of other mechanics that provide the same function. **A workaround to improve user experience is to use `prompt=none` when you invoke the `/authorize` endpoint**. This will not display the login dialog or the consent dialog. In addition to that **if you call `/authorize` from a hidden iframe and extract the new access token from the parent frame, then the user will not see the redirects happening**.

(source: [Auth0 - Which OAuth 2.0 flow should I use?](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use#is-the-client-a-native-app-or-a-spa-); emphasis is mine)

Comment: One thing that stands out here is that we're really not that interested in building a fully-fledged identity provider. We do use the password grant-type because we're only using this stuff internally. In addition, we're not using cookies/sessions at all and just storing the access/refresh token in browser storage.

Comment: In your option A for example there's "User accesses URL and changes password; ". This is something which is done in our SPA, but it needs to communicate with our internal API to do this. The lost password grant_type is _not_ for 3rd parties. Just for us.

Comment: In addition, our OAuth sever and resource server are one and the same thing.

Comment: Likewise, if we ever expose this API to third parties, they would not get access to the `password` grant type. That's just something we need in our internal API to exchange the username and password with access tokens.

Comment: If it's for internal consumption and is not to be available on public networks then it's hard to make recommendations; the threat model is completely different and most of OAuth2 and/or OpenID Connect could be seen as overkill for those situations. Go with what's simpler to implement and still delivers the security your specific requirements need.

Comment: It is for internal consumption as in that we are both the consumer and the service, but this will happen over the web. We basically need a sane/secure way for the client to say: "here's a one-time token, please give me an access token". It made sense to me to do do this within the OAuth2 framework as opposed to writing something standalone.

Comment: As a general rule if it's available over the internet I would avoid keeping refresh tokens in browser storage which is one of the reasons I favored implicit flow over ROPC; although implicit is not a silver-bullet and comes with its own issues I would still go down that route with an `/authorize` endpoint supporting sessions. **--** Having said that, if for you it's not worthwhile to go this route you can also consider [RFC 7523](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7523), it has nothing to do with password resets, but it does have the exchange token for token semantics.

Comment: Thanks! Good starting point. I know this is getting off-topic, but I don't really see why a session is more secure than storing and using a refresh token. Being cookie-less means we completely eliminate CSRF and the refresh token reduces the chance of it being embedded/logged in the wrong place.

Comment: You're right that sessions with cookies have the side-effect of having to worry about CSRF; my big issue with refresh tokens is that they are generally really long-lived which increase the window of time where an attack can be accomplished and browserland is like the wild wild west... with access tokens the risk is lowered by the fact that they are short-lived and with sessions they are based on HTTP-only cookies and also usually have shorter lifetimes than refresh tokens. It's difficult to say one is always better than the other.